# How can I get my binary tree insert function to work?

Tags: java, binary-tree

/ Solved /
I actually passed null. Since it doesn't contain any information, adding values to it won't affect my tree, thanks for the answer!

We have got a task in Java to create a binary tree which can hold integer. We have to write an insert function which inserts an integer to a tree by coincidence. I have now written the function but somehow it doesn't add the values I put in.

My class consists of an integer "value" and two references for the left and right branch, "left" and "right".
Also, I have to write this function in this way, so they have to return void, I am aware that there are easier ways.

So, for now, I already know that I get to the leaf. Then it's t == null. When I try, then to put "t = new CONSTRUCTOR(value, ...)"
it doesn't change anything.

```
public void insert_in_tree(int i) {
    /*Creating random number*/
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rand_num = rand.nextInt(2);
    if(rand_num == 0) { 
        setLeft(this.left, i);
    } else {
        setRight(this.right, i);
    }
}
```

... here is the code for the "setLeft" (The "setRight" function is the same, I just pass the right subtree when I am calling it) function:

```
void setLeft(IntBinTree t, int value) {
    if(t == null) {
        t = new IntBinTree(value, null, null);
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    /*Random number*/
    Random rand = new Random();
    int rand_num = rand.nextInt(2);
    /*Calling either left or right*/
    if(rand_num == 0) setLeft(t.left, value);
    setRight(t.right, value);
}
```

I suppose, the error is calling the function and changing then the local variable "t" instead of using "this". However, since I am passing a reference of "this", there shouldn't be any problem in doing this, can anyone spot the error?

Comment: You're more likely to get the answer you seek if you can supply a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where is the error taking place?

Comment: It was just that my tree didn't add any values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a null to a function. NOT an object.

If you passed an object (e.g. "this"), it would pass the reference to that object (in reality, Java is "[Pass by value](https://www.journaldev.com/3884/java-is-pass-by-value-and-not-pass-by-reference)", but what you pass by value is the reference, NOT the object itself) and any changes to it would reflect outside the function.

Passing a null would NOT do that since there is no object reference and you are just passing a value of "null" which has NOTHING to do with your original object, so any changes to "t" made inside the second function are lost.

What you should do is one of 2 things:

1. Pass "this" and a left/right flag.
2. Create left/right sub-tree (if empty) in the caller, pass the newly created and assigned subtree.

By the way, you have nearly identical code for left/right in the top level method and in set method - it would be easier to keep it entirely in the set method.